# Fixed element inside scrollable div acts as scroll trap

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a peculiar problem.

I have a scrollable div container, which also contains an element that has `position:fixed`.
The reason for this structure that in my actual environment i sometimes set it to `position:absolute`, to scroll with the container's content.

The problem is that as soon as the cursor is above the fixed div, it's impossible to scroll the container. This seems to be because fixed divs are related to the body rather than their parent.

To clarify please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LwY2j/4/

How can I disable this and always scroll the scrollcontainer, regardless of where the mouse is?

regards,
J

Comment: i dont know it is scrolling me fine i put cursor on many places to check

Comment: This has been answered in here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494850/a-way-to-scroll-an-underlying-div-when-mouse-is-on-top-of-a-fixed-div?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @Jaypal thanks! this does indeed work! (i prefer the pointer-events:none solution, since it requires no JS.)