# Scroll not working while hovering fixed element

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-position

To make this short, I have a site with two  tags, one fixed to the left and one fixed to the right of the screen. When you're not hovering them, you can scroll as usual but when you mouse over them you can no longer scroll until you mouse out of them.

The site is - http://www.kuhlswaine.com

Here are the two  tags I'm referring to along with their CSS -

### CSS & HTML

```css
    #hover-zone-left {
      background-color: transparent;
      height: 100%;
      left: 0;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 10%;
      z-index: 9;
    }
    #hover-zone-right {
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      height: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      right: 16px;
      top: 0;
      width: 10%;
      z-index: 99999;
    }
```

```html
<a id="hover-zone-left" class="prev-button special-anchor hover-zone" href="#"></a>
<a id="hover-zone-right" class="next-button special-anchor hover-zone" href="#"></a>
```

Comment: Please disregard any messy HTML/CSS, I've inherited this project from the previous person who built it so I apologize in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A way to scroll an underlying div when mouse is on top of a fixed div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494850/a-way-to-scroll-an-underlying-div-when-mouse-is-on-top-of-a-fixed-div)

Comment: I did come across that question, and I tried to implement the solution for it but did not have any luck.

Comment: Just so that solution can be ruled out, can you show how you implemented it and describe the results? Did any Javascript errors pop up in the console?

Comment: I tried placing this code in the header and then in the footer -  
`$('.hover-zone').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    $('#home').scrollTop($('#home').scrollTop() - (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail*30));
  });`  
Where the two items with the class .hover-zone would be targeted inside the container #home

Comment: In the current code on http://www.kuhlswaine.com/, there's a `<a id="home">` that loads before `<div id="home">` is added dynamically. jQuery is likely returning the link when you call `$('#home')`.

Comment: I see, can you provide a cleaner way you would write that in order to get it to behave the intended way?

Comment: If you just change the ID of that link (e.g. `<a id="home_link">`), the jQuery solution might start working for you.

Comment: I tried  `<script type="text/javascript">
$('.hover-zone').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) { $('#test').scrollTop($('#test').scrollTop() - (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail*30)); });`  where I added the id #test to the container with the class .slides  That seemed to have no effect either.

Comment: Note the Javascript error that page is generating: `TypeError: $(...).on is not a function`. The version of jQuery where `.on()` was added [was 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/on/), and your page is running version 1.4.2.

Comment: So all I should need to do is update the jQuery file to 1.7 or above and that will enable this to work?