# Allow site contents to scroll below a fixed positioned element

Tags: css, scroll, position, fixed, off-canvas-menu

I am trying to implement an off canvas menu in my Wordpress site. Instructions on coding the menu are taken from this site:

http://tympanus.net/Development/OffCanvasMenuEffects/sideslide.html

The problem is that when you open the menu and the mouse is on the menu I cannot scroll the site contents beneath the menu. This is specially important in the mobile version since the menu takes much of the space on the screen so being able to scroll the site contents is very important.

So basically I want the menu to not be scrollable, but the site contents should always be scrollable whether the menu is visible or not.

Comment: can you post what you've done so far?

Comment: @howard-e - I have just added the code to my dev site at localhost exactly as it is on tympanus.net. If you go to the link I mentioned you will see that this problem exists there as well, so if we manage to fix it there, that will fix my issue as well.

Comment: When the menu is open, you won't be able to scroll the window while the mouse is on the menu.  This object does't work that way, since the menu is an overlay if you're hovering on that you are controlling the menu and not what's behind it.

Comment: But how does it work in here: http://www.brfsjohuset.se/
I want to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Check out SIDR https://www.berriart.com/sidr/

Comment: Thanks for the link. It looks interesting, but I have already implemented the other one and only this one problem needs to be fixed. On the other hand the SIDR pushes the main content to the left or to the right, I want it as an overlay.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using the javascript fixes mentioned here:

[A way to scroll an underlying div when mouse is on top of a fixed div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494850/a-way-to-scroll-an-underlying-div-when-mouse-is-on-top-of-a-fixed-div)

@howard-e Thanks for taking the time to look at this.