# How to enable scrolling over fixed element?

Tags: javascript, css, layout

I have a problem with scrolling over fixed element, it doesn't work on my site. But I saw that there is no such problem in some scrolling examples like [this one](http://stutrek.github.io/scrollMonitor/demos/fixed.html). After a while I found a little difference - on my site the scrolling of the page is not on the `html` tag but on the of app's root tag.

Here you can find an example of the situation that I have - you can't scroll over the red block http://jsbin.com/rutogosesa/edit?html,css,output, and here an example where you can scroll over the red block http://jsbin.com/munixamuqo/edit?html,css,output.

My quesion is: how to allow scrolling in first example. I know that I can subscribe on `onwheel` event and move scrollbar mannually, but it looks weird as all browsers have smooth scrolling my implementation will broke its behaviour, especially for mac users. Maybe there are some other possible solutions?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't use the CSS from the second example in your first example?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/dinenumaqe/edit?html,css,output , there

Comment: Having the `#app {overflow: scroll}` combined with the `html {overflow: hidden}` means if the window is shorter than `#push` you can send the scrollbar off the screen. Is that really the goal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A way to scroll an underlying div when mouse is on top of a fixed div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494850/a-way-to-scroll-an-underlying-div-when-mouse-is-on-top-of-a-fixed-div)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's boil your trouble down to this: if the mouse is over `#inner`, you can't use the usual methods (spacebar, arrow keys, trackpad, wheel) to scroll `#outer` up and down.

If you need to keep everything you have, get around this by adding `pointer-events: none` to the inner element. (Note that this means you won't be able to interact with it at all - so any links in the inner element won't be clickable. Given the examples you gave in your question, that won't be a problem.)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#inner {
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  pointer-events: none; /* this is your fix. note it doesn't work in IE < 9 */
}
#outer {
  overflow-y: auto; /* I changed this from "scroll". that may have been an inappropriate change, but it seems like it's probably desirable - you don't want the scrollbar to show even if the window is tall enough that you can't scroll */
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}
#push {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">

  <p>top of #outer</p>

  <div id="inner">
    #inner
  </div>

  <div id="push" />
</div>
```

If you can get away with changing your `html`'s styles, you can work around this by dropping the `html {height: 100%; overflow: hidden}`. This solution doesn't use `pointer-events: none` so you'll still be able to interact with the inner element!

```css
html {
  margin: 0; /* dropped html {height: 100%; overflow: hidden} */
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#inner {
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#outer {
  overflow-y: auto; /* I changed this from "scroll". that may have been an inappropriate change, but it seems like it's probably desirable - you don't want the scrollbar to show even if the window is tall enough that you can't scroll */
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}
#push {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">

  <p>top of #outer</p>

  <div id="inner">
    #inner
  </div>

  <div id="push"></div>
</div>
```